# Python: Conditional Exit based on user input

Tags: python

Just need this for a game program. At the end of the Rock-Paper-Scissors program it asks if the user wants to play again or not, and uses `sys.exit()` to terminate the program. However, instead of terminating the program if the user enters something that isn't 'Y' or 'y' in the `replayFunc()` function, it goes into the code under the `except:` block in `main()`. Any help is appreciated.

```
import random
import os
import sys

userOS = str(sys.platform)

def clearFunc():
  if "win32" not in userOS:
    os.system('clear')
  else:
    os.system('cls')

def replayFunc():
  exitPrompt = input("Do you want to play again? (Y/N): ")
  if exitPrompt == 'Y' or exitPrompt == 'y':
    main()
  else:
    sys.exit(0)


def main():
  oppChoice = random.randint(1,3)
  playerChoice = int
  print("Welcome to Rock-Paper-Scissors!")
  input("\nPress Enter to continue: ")
  clearFunc()

  try:
    playerChoice = int(input("Please use 1-3 to select from the list below:\n\n1. Rock\n2. Paper\n3. Scissors\n"))
    if playerChoice == 1 and oppChoice == 1:
      print("You tied!")
      replayFunc()
    elif playerChoice == 1 and oppChoice == 2:
      print("Computer Wins!")
      replayFunc()
    elif playerChoice == 1 and oppChoice == 3:
      print("You win!")
      replayFunc()

    elif playerChoice == 2 and oppChoice == 1:
      print("You win!")
      replayFunc()
    elif playerChoice == 2 and oppChoice == 2:
      print("You tied!")
      replayFunc()
    elif playerChoice == 2 and oppChoice == 3:
      print("Computer Wins!")
      replayFunc()

    elif playerChoice == 3 and oppChoice == 1:
      print("Computer wins!")
      replayFunc()
    elif playerChoice == 3 and oppChoice == 2:
      print("You win!")
      replayFunc()
    elif playerChoice == 3 and oppChoice == 3:
      print("You tied!")
      replayFunc()
    else:
      print("Didn't get that")
      main()


  except:
    print("TypeError")
    main()

main()
```

Comment: I think you should re-think the flow of the your program. It seems to call `main()` recursively over and over. If the user stays in the game long enough, the stack will be full. In a programming language with tail-call optimization, this may be OK, but Python is definitely not such a language.

Comment: @NickLee: I have a hard time imagining someone wanting to play hundreds of games of Rock, Paper, Scissors against the computer, but yes, in general this is a bad design. :-)

Comment: What would you suggest for a rewrite to make this optimized?

Comment: @JimnorRain: An infinite loop around the repeated code in `main` (`while True:`) with appropriate `break` and `continue` usage in place of recursive calls would avoid the unbounded recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.exit(0)` is basically implemented as `raise SystemExit(0)`. It's an exception, because you *need* to bubble up so context managers (`with` statements) and `finally` blocks can clean up properly.

[The reason bare `except:` is frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/364696) is because it catches even exceptions that shouldn't be caught, e.g. `SystemExit`. So stop using it, and catch only exceptions you know how to handle, or at least change it to `except Exception:` which won't catch the special, shouldn't be caught exceptions (like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt`).